# TAQ-complete spectra and homotopy completion

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I read an article about Homotopy completion and top. Quillen homology from Harper-Hess.

There for any operad $O$ in spectra and $O$-algebra $X$ a completion tower
$$\kappa: X \to holim_{n\geq 1} \tau_n(O) \circ_O X$$ is constructed. Here $\tau_n(O)$ is the $n$-truncated operad
having only operations below or equal degree $n.$

For which spectra the map $\kappa$ is an equivalence?
Is $\kappa$ an equivalence if $O=\partial_*id$ is the spectral Lie operad
given by the Goodwillie derivatives of the identity and $X=H(\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: Harper and Hess proved that the  map is an equivalence if $X$ is $0$-connected and all the spectra that make up $O$ are $-1$-connected. Regarding your last question, it presupposes a $\partial_* Id$-algebra structure on $H\mathbb Q$. As far as I can tell the only possible algebra structure is the trivial one. Is this what you really want?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I want to see $H(\mathbb{Q})$ as endowed with the trivial $\partial_*id$-algebra structure.  What can we say abou that?

Comment: For $X$ a trivial $O$-algebra the cofiber of the map $\tau_{n}(O) \circ_O X \to \tau_{n-1}(O) \circ_O X$ is computed as $O(n) \circ Sym(X)= O(n) \otimes_{h\Sigma_n}  Sym(X)^{\otimes n},$ where $Sym(X)$ is the symmetric algebra.  
  For $O=\partial_*Id$ the $n$-th layer in the Goodwillie tower of the identity of spectra, i.e. the cofiber of the map $P_n(Id) (X)\to P_{n-1}(Id)(X)$ is  $ O(n) \otimes_{h\Sigma_n}  X^{\otimes n}.$ What is the relationship between these two towers?